# Find the difference between two epoch times that are in filename

Tags: linux, find

I have a bunch of Splunk buckets (directories) that contain two epoch timestamps in their names.  I need to find a way to perform a find on those filenames to locate any files that whose second epoch time is between  1488344400 (March 1, 2017) and 1497499200 (June 15, 2017).  The format of the filename is as follows:

```
db_1274129994_1273525194_0 (db_latesttime_earliesttime_idnum)
```

The "earliesttime" is the determining factor as the latest can extend past the dates.

Comment: Please read your question and explain: what do you want find, how, what does that have to do with directories with funny names, what do you mean by "second epoch time" of a file, what does this have to do with "earliesttime".

Comment: If you look at the file name there are two epoch times listed in it - the second time is what I am interested in,  I need to perform a find on the filenames in the range listed above that pertain only to the first epoch in the file name.

Comment: What I'd like to do is read your question and understand what you're asking, without needing further input.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash`:

```
for d in db_*_*_*; do
    if [[ "$d" =~ db_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*) ]]; then
        if [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" -ge 1488344400 ]] &&
           [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" -le 1497499200 ]]; then
            printf 'Found "%s"\n' "$d"
        fi
    fi
done
```

This iterates over all `db_*_*_*` names in the current directory.  If any name matches the regular expression `db_([0-9]*)_([0-9]*)`, then a numerical comparison is carried out on the last of the two found numbers in the name.  If the comparison comes out true, then the name is reported on standard output.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls /path/to/your/buckets | awk -F_ '$3 >= 1488344400 && $3 <= 1497499200'
```

Note: in the general case, ***one must not parse `ls`***, but since we know that our filenames won't contain special characters, we shouldn't get into trouble *in this particular case*.

As for the `awk`: we simply define `_` as the field separator and print all lines where the third field ("earliesttime" according to you) is between the epoch times you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

With **bash**:

```
for f in db_[0-9]*_[0-9]*; do 
    e_time="${f:14:10}"    # extracting 'earliest time'
    if [ $e_time -ge 1488344400 ] && [ $e_time -le 1497499200 ]; then 
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @n.st, will someone live till that time `20 November 2286` ? For now, we have fixed format described  in the question

Comment: Maybe not *until* that time, but (hopefully) *at* that time. Do not underestimate the longevity of "quick and dirty" hacks! I am joking, of course. Still, it doesn't hurt to keep in mind the limitations you're dealing with (like with parsing `ls` in my solution).

Comment: Minor warning on the loop glob expression: It looks like a regular expression, but it ain't.